# How do I exclude a ./. directory from a shell script search?

Tags: macos, shell, search

I'm trying to do a search for all image files more than X by Y pixels in directory /Users/ (this is Mac OS, and yes, a 'dangerous' search, I know.)

```
int main( ){
  FILE *pf;
   pf = popen("cd ~/ ; find . -type f '!' '(' -path ".*" ')' -print0 | xargs -0 file | grep 'image data'","r"); 
 }
```

This gives the error `find: ./.fseventsd: Permission denied`. **I need to skip any directories starting with** `.` but can't seem to get it to work using the above `! ( -path ".*" )` command.

Lots of info out there about how to skip *files*; can't seem to find any about *directories*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-path . only matches '.' so try

```
find . -type f '!' '(' -path "./.[a-z]*" ')'
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to do something like `( -type d -name '.*' -prune ) -or ( $EXP -print )` where `$EXP` is the rest of your expression. That will prune any directories who's name matches ".*", and then it will apply your expression to everything else. The presence of `print` at the end is meant to be ANDed with the rest of your expression and it's used here to prevent the pruned directory from printing.

Comment: That looks promising and I don't get an error; however with `( -type d -name '.*' -prune ) -or` I don't get any output.

Comment: Of course you didn't get any output. You omitted the second half. The full expression you want based on what you have above is going to look like `\( -type d -name '.*' prune \) -or \( -type f -print0 \)` (I skipped your `-path` primary because I think that was trying to prune dot-folders).

Comment: Haha, no, I had `-print`... `find . -type f '!' '(' -path "./.[a-z]*" ')' -print | xargs -0 file | grep 'image data' | tr '\012' '\000'` still gives no output, but simply `find . -type f '!' '(' -path "./.[a-z]*" ')' -print` does. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Oh. `-print0` vs `-print`. Got it.